# Open an Excel File in Mac using Silverlight OOB

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-5.0

in windows I know I can use automationfactory for wsscript to open the excel file, we need to be able to do the same in mac but sadly the best I can do is use a save file dialog and ask the user to save the file first before working on it.

Is there a way to open a file in Mac using Silverlight?

Comment: Mac + Silverlight + Excel ... best bet is to launch Preview for the Excel.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? thanks

Comment: It is possible that i pass the file uri on a webbrowser control so that the browser control would open an open/save dialog? Currently i am experiencing an invalid operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Excel for MAC, and put the file uri on a Hyperlink button Navigate Uri and it opens the excel :)